# LINQ Implementation query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I am setting two values based on two different conditions inside for each. Is it possible to implement the below in LINQ ?

```
foreach(Customer cust in Customers)
{
    If(Condition 1)
            condtion1Var =true;
    If(Condition2 )
            condition2Var =true;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to implement it in LINQ?

Comment: well, we have been asked to evaluate the use of LINQ wherever we are using for-each. My feeling is both for-each and linq have their places and no point in blindly replacing for-each with LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
condition1Result = customers.Any(cust => Condition1(cust));
condition2Result = customers.Any(cust => Condition2(cust));
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in single LINQ query ?

Comment: Possibly, but I personally agree with your comment above.